# Can add static class in Project

Tags: xamarin.android

I have following questions for my Xamarin Android project :

1) Can add static class in the project ? Below class is used in WinRT project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MobileSales.DataModel
{
   static class TransItemSelected
    {

       public static int DocType { get; set; }
       public static string DocNo { get; set; }
       public static int TransId { get; set; }

      ....

    }
}
```

2) How to get and set data for the above class inside the Activity.cs

3) How to setUp the project to be used in Android tablet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes (but not recommended in many cases)

2) TransItemSelected.DocType = 0;

3) Include the file in Android project (class library or application)

Do make the class public though.

```
public static class TransItemSelected
{
     ....
```

Comment: May I ask Why Cannot use static Class?

Comment: You can, there isn't anything preventing its usage.

Comment: If your class does not maintain state if can be static. It is not good practice though to use static classes if they need to maintain state, use regular instanced classes instead.